# How to add a customized legend on my ggplot2 column chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have the following R codes running in RStudio:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggthemes)
library(scales)

DF <- structure(list(Period = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                          2L), .Label = c("Current", "SPLY"), class = "factor"), 
                     variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Wk 06 Jan 2020-12 Jan 2020", "Wk 13 Jan 2020-19 Jan 2020", "Wk 20 Jan 2020-26 Jan 2020", "Wk 27 Jan 2020-02 Feb 2020"), class = "factor"), value = c(6212, 12195,5508,      10574,15060,    9763,5341,      9478)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), .Names = c("Period", "variable", "value"), class = "data.frame")


circle_df <- data.frame(variable = 1:4 + 0.4, value = rep( 1000, 4),
                        labels = scales::percent(1- DF$value[DF$Period == "SPLY"]/
                                                   DF$value[DF$Period == "Current"]))


p<- ggplot(DF, aes(variable, value)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = max_y), data = diff_df, fill = "grey80", width =0.4) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = Period), position = "dodge", width = 0.5) +
  geom_text(aes(label=scales::comma(value), group=Period), position = position_dodge(width = 0.5), fontface="bold",
            vjust=3.0) +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::comma(diff), y = max_y), vjust=-0.5, 
            data = diff_df %>% filter(sim_higher), 
            hjust = 0.0, colour = scales::muted("red")) +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::comma(diff), y = max_y), vjust=-0.5, 
            data = diff_df %>% filter(!sim_higher), 
            hjust = 1.0, colour = scales::muted("red")) +
  geom_point(data = circle_df, fill="greenyellow", shape = 21, size= 20, colour = "white") +
  geom_text(data = circle_df, aes(label = labels), colour = "black", family="Trebuchet MS",fontface="bold") +
    theme_minimal()+
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(), axis.text.y=element_blank(), axis.ticks.y=element_blank(), axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 11, hjust = .5, vjust = .5, face = "bold")) +
  ylab('Room Nights') + xlab('Week') +
  
  ggtitle("ALL HOTELS: Pick Up (Room Nights) in January 2020")

p
```

The output of the above codes is shown below.

[image: Current Output]

My expected output is shown below:

(1) Remove "Period" in the legend

(2) Add icons for "Variance"and "%"Change"

[image: Expected output]

How can I modify my existing codes to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, this takes quite a lot of hacking of different scales to achieve:

```
mutate(DF, Period = factor(Period, levels = c("Current", "SPLY", "Variance")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(variable, value)) +
    geom_col(aes(y = max_y), data = diff_df, fill = "grey80", width = 0.4) +
    geom_col(aes(fill = Period), position = "dodge", width = 0.5) +
    geom_text(aes(label=scales::comma(value), group = Period), 
              position = position_dodge(width = 0.5), fontface = "bold", vjust = 3.0) +
    geom_text(aes(label = scales::comma(diff), y = max_y), vjust = -0.5, 
              data = diff_df %>% filter(sim_higher), 
              hjust = 0.0, colour = scales::muted("red")) +
    geom_text(aes(label = scales::comma(diff), y = max_y), vjust = -0.5, 
              data = diff_df %>% filter(!sim_higher), 
              hjust = 1.0, colour = scales::muted("red")) +
    geom_point(data = circle_df, aes(colour = "", shape = "", size = ""))+
    geom_point(data = circle_df, fill = "yellowgreen", shape = 21, 
               color = "white", size = 20) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#F8766D", "#00BFC4", "gray80"), 
                      drop = FALSE, name = " ") +
    scale_size_manual(guide = "legend", breaks = "", values = 10,
                      name = "% change") +
    scale_color_manual(guide = "legend",  breaks = "", 
                       values = "yellowgreen", name = "% change") +
    scale_shape_manual(guide = "legend",  breaks = "", 
                       values = 16, name = "% change") +
    geom_text(data = circle_df, aes(label = labels), colour = "black", 
              family="Trebuchet MS",fontface="bold") +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(), 
          axis.text.y=element_blank(), 
          axis.ticks.y=element_blank(), 
          axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
          axis.text.x = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 11, 
                                     hjust = .5, vjust = .5, face = "bold")) +
    labs(y = "Room Nights", x = "Week", fill = "") +
    ggtitle("ALL HOTELS: Pick Up (Room Nights) in January 2020")
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! This is art! Which part should I modify if I want that circle in the legend to be smaller (or is it picking up the existing circle size inside the graph)?

Comment: @user3115933 yes, you can make it smaller by reducing the values = 20 in the scale_size_manual call

Comment: When I change the size to 10, it also changes the size of the circles inside the graph. My point was whether the size of the circle in the legend can be changed independently.

Comment: @user3115933 yes, though it requires plotting some smaller green points behind your large points - see my update

Comment: Thanks a lot! Highly appreciated.